# Calling SVN commands from a java program

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, command

I want to call SVN commands (update , commit) from a java program. any help ?

SVN : Tortoise SVN
Environment : java program will be running inside a jBoss server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a really, really bad idea to use a GUI SVN client from within an app server. While TortoiseSVN [can be scripted](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), it's still a GUI application, and an unexpected situation can cause it to pop up a dialog on your server (and some tasks may always open a dialog).

It,s much, much better ot use a Java implementation of SVN, such as [SvnKit](http://svnkit.com/) - then you can work with a nice Java API and your question becomes moot.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, there are several libraries out there that do the job. Personally, I'd either go with [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) or with the [Maven SCM](http://maven.apache.org/scm/) abstraction (the latter is less powerful but more portable).

Answer (score 4):

It's probably simplest to use [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) which is a native implementation of SVN in Java, provided you can get the version to match your command-line client version if you need to share working copies between them.

It's under a copy-left-ish licence, but as long as you're running the code on your own server and not distributing it that should be OK (but IANAL, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/), a java library for interacting with SVN workspaces. It is used by IntelliJ and Eclipse plugins to provide SVN support.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search brought up http://svnkit.com/